# Ion.RangeSlider, slider width and position on update

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a carousel which can be moved by `Ion.RangeSlider`. Slider width depends on number of carousel items.

Carousel itself also can be moved by mouse drag. I want to also update slider position when carousel is dragged so I initialized update for slider.

But when I update slider, it lost style attribute. So i made it to calculate this again. But also slider position appears to be not in the center at expected point, it moves to right.

Maybe it's easier to understand when viewing demo:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mwams6g2/13/)

Try to drag carousel to the end and you will see what the problem is.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     var itemsNum = 0;

var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.on('initialized.owl.carousel', function(event) {
 var itemCount =  event.item.count;
  var size      = event.page.size;
  var dragLength = 100 / (itemCount/size);
  $("#range").ionRangeSlider({
    type: "single",
    min: 1,
    max: itemCount - (size - 1),
    keyboard: true,
    step: 1,
    onChange: function (data) {
      //owl.trigger('changed.owl.carousel', [???]);
          owlTo = (data.from) - 1;
          owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [owlTo, 500, true]);
    }
  });
  $('.irs-slider.single').css('width', dragLength + "%")
});

//Слайдер
owl.owlCarousel({
    loop:false,
    margin:10,
    nav:false,
    dots: false,
    slideBy:1,
    items: 8,
    responsiveClass:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:2
        },
        500:{
            items:3
        },
        600:{
            items:4
        },
        700:{
            items:5
        },
        800:{
            items:6
        },
        900:{
            items:7
        },
        1000:{
            items:8
        }
    }
});

owl.on('dragged.owl.carousel', function(event) {
  var itemCount =  event.item.count;
   var size      = event.page.size;
   var curItem = event.item.index + 1;
   var dragLength = 100 / (itemCount/size);
   console.log(curItem);
  $("#range").data("ionRangeSlider").update({from: curItem});
  $('.irs-slider.single').css('width', dragLength + "%");
});

owl.on('resized.owl.carousel', function(event) {
 var itemCount =  event.item.count;
  var size      = event.page.size;
  var curItem = event.item.index + 1;
  var dragLength = 100 / (itemCount/size);
  $("#range").data("ionRangeSlider").update({
   max: itemCount - (size - 1),
    from: curItem
  });
  $('.irs-slider.single').css('width', dragLength + "%");
});                  
                       
})
```

```css
.owl-carousel .owl-item {
    background-color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
}

.irs-bar, .irs-bar-edge, .irs-min, .irs-max, .irs-from, .irs-to, .irs-single{opacity: 0;}

.irs-slider.single {
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.0.0-beta.3/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.0.0-beta.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.0.0-beta.3/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/static/css/ion.rangeSlider.skinHTML5.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/static/js/ion-rangeSlider/ion.rangeSlider.js"></script>
<link href="http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/static/css/ion.rangeSlider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
</div>

<div style="position: relative; padding: 20px 100px;">
    <div><input type="text" id="range" value="" name="range" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The script is almost correct.

In the part where you update the ionRangeSlider after you dragged the owl.carousel there is:

`var curItem = event.item.index + 1;`.

That should be:

`var curItem = event.item.index - 1;`.

Check this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/broezer/mwams6g2/28/

This only applies to a gallery of 4 items in a row.

*update*

However I do notice some quirks with the responsiveness.
So i reckon, it has to do something with that part of the script.

After some testing I found that changing values of items & the update function on the drag are related to each other. So be aware of this quirk.
You can set breakpoints in your drag function to change `var curItem` according to the breakpoints you defined in you `owl.owCarousel` settings